# How to make a variadic template method that takes references rather than copies?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, variadic-templates

We have a template method that generically executes some member function in parallel, according to the number of system threads available, using a thread pool.

Two of the arguments this method must take are *fixed*, the first being the thread index and the second being the number of threads.

This is so these methods can do something like the following:

```
for(i = threadIndex; i < workContainer.size(); i += numThreads) 
{
  // So this thread will only do every numThreads piece of the work from the workContainer, with no overlap between threads
}
```

This is good, and here is what that method looks like:

```
  template <class S, class Args>
  void parallelWork(S* self, void (S::*workfcn)(const unsigned, const unsigned, Args*), Args* args)
  {
    auto work = [&](const unsigned threadIndex, const unsigned nthreads, S* self, Args* args)

    {
      std::string* rc = nullptr;

      try
        {
          (self->*workfcn)(threadIndex, nthreads, args);
        }
      catch (std::exception& err)
        {
          rc = new std::string(err.what());
        }

      return rc;
    };

    ulong nthreads = size();
    std::vector<std::string*> rc(nthreads);

    if (1 == nthreads)
      {
        rc[0] = work(0, 1, self, args);
      }
    else
      {
        std::vector<std::future<std::string*>> frc(nthreads);

        for (unsigned i = 0; nthreads > i; ++i)
          frc[i] = enqueue(work, i, nthreads, self, args);

        // Wait for all
        for (unsigned i = 0; nthreads > i; ++i)
          rc[i] = frc[i].get();
      }

    for (unsigned i = 0; nthreads > i; ++i)
      {
        if (rc[i])
          {
            HELAS_ERROR(std::string("Thread ") + std::to_string(i) + ": " + *rc[i]); delete rc[i];
          }
      }
  }
```

However, this is limited. The current solution requires that we effectively put all of the arguments (some of which are references) into a structure, and then pass a pointer to that structure to this `parallelWork()` method.

Wouldn't it be great, if instead we could *directly* pass the arguments the method should take? IE, instead of doing this:

```
struct ThreadArgs 
{
  const std::vector<int>& inArg1;
  double inArg2;
  SomeClass* inarg3;
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> outArg1; // outer vector is per-thread
}
```

```
void MyClass::doFooInParallel() 
{
  std::vector<int> inArg1;
  double inArg2;
  SomeClass* cp = getSomeClass();
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> outArg1(numThreads);

  ThreadArgs args = ThreadArgs(inArg1, inArg2, cp, outArg1);

  parallelWork(this, &MyClass::foo, &args);
}
```

We could do this:

```
void MyClass::doFooInParallel() 
{
  std::vector<int> inArg1;
  double inArg2;
  SomeClass* cp = getSomeClass();
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> outArg1(numThreads);

  parallelWork(this, &MyClass::foo, inArg1, inArg2, cp, outArg1);
}
```

It seems like a variadic template would be the solution, changing the start of the method to this:

```
  template <class S, class... Args>
  void parallelWork(S* self,void (S::*workfcn)(const unsigned, const unsigned, Args... args),Args... args)
  {
    auto work = [&](const unsigned threadIndex, const unsigned nthreads,S* self, Args... args)
```

And this does compile with our current usage of the method. However, there is a problem - these arguments are pass-by-value instead of pass-by-reference.

For inputs this may not be bad and some may be eliminated by copy elision. But for variables passed which are *outputs* of the method (like a vector nthreads in size with output from each thread), that obviously doesn't work - it will mean doing the work in parallel results in nothing being actually done.

I tried making them references like so:

```
  template <class S, class... Args>
  void parallelWork(S* self,void (S::*workfcn)(const unsigned, const unsigned, Args&&... args),Args&&... args)
  {
    auto work = [&](const unsigned threadIndex, const unsigned nthreads,S* self, Args&&... args)
```

However, this fails when we try to use it.

`could not match type-parameter 0-1&& against (the actual parameter we tried to pass)`

(Single-reference also failed, but I tested just in case)

What may be a solution to this? Is it possible in C++11, or only with features from later C++ standards?

Would `std::forward` or `std::ref` or `std::cref` help at all here somehow?

This is really more of a conceptual question, so please forgive me that all of this code can't be run, it'd be an enormous amount of work to get a runnable example of all this up and I think the question is explained well enough to cover it, but let me know if it needs to be clarified.

Comment: I attempted using ```Args&``` and get the same error, that the compiler cannot match ```type-parameter 0-1&``` against the actual parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`&&` is not a reference but a r-value (which can either be a reference or a value). You should use `Args& ...`. I think the problem is that you are using `template <class S, class... Args>` where you should use `template <class S, typename... Args>` as it seems that your arguments are not always classes.

If you want to use forwarding (like `std::vector.emplace_back` for example), you can use `Args && ...` and then `std::forward` your argument to the function. In your case you should note that using `std::forward` will still pass your argument by value and not by reference. To achieve passing the argument by r-value use `std::move` instead!

Comment: Tentatively, your solution seems to work! Changing to ```Args&...``` and using ```typename...``` seems to have fixed it. At the very least, it compiles. After some more testing to make sure it's actually working, I can mark this as solved.

Comment: Uhmmm... in that context (template parameters declaration), `typename` and `class` are almost completely interchangeable (and `class` can also intercept a non-class type, as `int`). The only difference I know is that, when you declare a template-template parameter as (by example) `template <template <typename...> class C>`, the last `class` can't be substituted by a `typename` before C++17 (but, starting from C++17, you can use also `typename`).